# What's the matter with 'const Obj' and 'Obj &'?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I want to write a class that is compatible for std::set, so I overload the "less than" operator like this. It works.

```
bool Segment::SVertex::operator<(const SVertex &rhs) const
{
    return id < rhs.id;
}
```

However, since I write Java more than C++, 'rhs.id' looks very uncomfortable to me. So I change it to 'rhs.getId()' where getId() is just a normal getter function:

```
long SVertex::getId(){return id;}
```

This turns out to be a compile time error: can't convert "this" pointer from "const Segment::SVertex" to "Segment::SVertex &"

(note that my VS2008 is not English and I translated the error message, so the line above is not necessarily exact)

I only know that '&' denotes passing by reference and 'const' forbids any changes. I don't exactly understand what's going on behind the scene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is your getter function isn't exactly 'normal'; your getter should be

```
long SVertex::getId() const
{return id;}
```

Note the **const** at the end: it tells the compiler/users that this method does not modify the class' internals. So, it's possible to use it in your operator < which is also const.
Const member functions can only call other member functions if they are also const; Non-const member functions can call any.

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed not normal ha-hah! I should change the way I think that formed from writing thousands line of Java code. My fault.

Answer (score 5):

Your getter must be constant:

```
long SVertex::getId() const {return id;}
```

This signals that it doesn't change the object.

Comment: I see, so in a nut, all functions must be const which are called by a const function.

Comment: Yes.  You can think of every member function as having an invisible first argument `SVertex *this`.  The syntax shown by @unwind is how you declare that argument `const SVertex *this`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `rhs` is `const`, so you are not allowed to change it. Your `getId` on the other hand doesn't promise not to change `this` - it also needs to be const:

```
int SVertex::getId() const { return id; }
```